# My Ubuntu 20.04 gets stuck many times. keyboard and mouse also do not respond

Tags: 20.04, kernel, freeze, disk-usage, logs

My Ubuntu 20.04 gets stuck many times. Keyboard and mouse also do not respond. `journalctl -r` logs file attached while system is stuck at around 9.30 AM:

[image: journalctl -r logs file attached while system stuck around 9.30 AM]

Comment: Do you have a question?   Your details are rather vague; there was no Ubuntu release is 2020-February (20.02), and if you're running Ubuntu 20.04.2 then you're *years* behind on applying security fixes thus I'd worry about that (*or you're not using Ubuntu at all, but a system based on Ubuntu thus the invalid/incorrect release details*).   Pictures of text are harder to read, so please help thus of us you've asked for help from, by making details clear & accurate.  Are you using Ubuntu? what release of Ubuntu? (*your details are unclear & contradict!*)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Comment: You're behind on applying security fixes, so I'd apply security fixes asap as a 20.04 or *focal* system has reported itself as 20.04.6 for some time (ie. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded **before** that date!).   This is a Q&A site, so please add clarifications or additional details to your question, don't comment them to yourself (*comments are from readers to the OP or Original Poster or prior commenter and **not** for additional details from OP; it's not a forum as https://ubuntuforums.org/ is that*)